# How do I write a sass code?

Tags: sass

I installed Ruby and entered "gem install sass" and created a style.scss file on ++notepad and entered "sass --watch style.scss:style.css" 
what I get: Sass is watching for changes.Press ctrl-c to stop.
            error no such a file or directory style.scss

style.scss is saved on my desktop.

Do I have to put it in specific directory..?

I just wantted to taste sass and went on codepen and just a simple code

```
 <div class="box"> </box>
```

sass

```
$blue: #3bbfce;
.box{background:$blue;}
```

that s what I get: Invalid CSS after "#3bbfce": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"

What am I doing wrong with sass?

Comment: When you type : sass --watch style.scss:style.css, take care if your style.scss is in your current directory

Comment: sorry but where is my current directory then? I have one style.scss and one style.css on my desktop and I give sass --watch style.scss:style.css ...still same

Comment: I just see that editor support.. and ++notepad isn't in the list. Can that be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your terminal commands from the directory where your .sass and .css files should live.  So in your command prompt, do something like `cd c:\Users\username\Desktop` or `cd ~\Desktop` - whichever is appropriate for your operating system.

Also note that Sass has two different syntaxes - .sass and .scss.  The .scss syntax uses brackets and nesting, but the .sass syntax uses whitspace for nesting.  It looks like you're writing .scss but you've set the syntax to .sass; so either change the syntax or use whitespace in your code.

Comment: I got it! Just one more question if it's oke.. I entered the command line and  "overwrite normal.css" so it's working i guess! I have one index.html file right! do i call normalcss.css file in my html or style.scss?
-and make changes on style.scss file and overwrite normalcss.css and expect it changes the style on html page? or am i totally on wrong page?

Comment: You should reference your .css file from your .html file. Sass will export the .css for you, based on the .sass or .scss file.  That's why you'll still include a .css file from .html like normal.

Answer (score 5):

That isn't SASS.

SASS doesn't use semi-colons or braces, and it's telling you as much. After `#3bbfce`, you have a semi-colon which is invalid syntax.

Here is the equivalent syntactically-correct SASS:

```
$blue: #3bbfce

.box
  background: $blue
```

If you want to use the S**C**SS variant which *does* use semi-colons and braces, you need to add `--scss` to your command line:

```
$ sass --scss --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Comment: I just saw semi-colons and braces here. but indeed when I changed on codepen just like you write then it works! Thanks! but I am still stuck on my server..